# adb install apk successful on device (or emulator), but not found

Tags: adb, installation, android-emulator

I am using command line to install apk on devices and emulators. There is only one device at one time, so I don't have to specify the device's name.

```
adb install file.apk
```

output:

```
Performing Streamed Install
Success
```

I check on the device (or emulator), but can't find the installed app.
Could you please help?

Comment: "*can't find the installed app*" did you mean it's not shown on the launcher (as with any apps having no launcher activity), or in the Settings-Apps list?

Comment: my app has the launcher activity. "can't find the installed app on device" literally means I don't see the installed app on the device or emulator.

Comment: Check whether the package is listed in the output of `adb shell pm list packages`. If yes, the problem is with your app per se because the app is still installed. May be try directly launching an activity through adb in that case. If not, you would have to dig into [tag:logcat] to see what goes on when the apk is getting installed.

Comment: Thanks @Firelord. Indeed, the package is in the list, but I don't see my app on the screen. Probably it's due to the app itself. I will try to run the app directly from adb.

Answer (score 7):

perform a full uninstall

```
adb uninstall <your-package-name>
```

then try reinstall your app

```
adb install app.apk
```

I faced this issue on the flutter release installation.

This problem happens because of different app signatures between debug and release

Answer (score 1):

I kid you not. In my case, I was comparing two apps(app1 and app2) and what I was actually doing was install the app2(adb install in app2 directory where the apk path and filename happened to be identical to app1), when I really meant to install app1, and it simply said "Install Success", which was true; the app2 was indeed installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `adb uninstall com.myname.myapp` *from a different machine*.
When I did it from my windows PC, it was failing because it did not find the app. When I did it from my ubuntu laptop, uninstalling worked. Subsequently running the installation from the original machine (Windows PC in my case) did work as well.